# How to install updates in Kali Linux

Tags: updates, kali-linux

I am new to Linux. I am using the `apt-get update` command to update Kali Linux, but it is returning the following errors:

```
rookie@kali:~$ apt-get update  
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
rookie@kali:~$
```

And the second error comes up when I try to open Social Engineer toolkit:

[image: SET Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sudo to run the `apt-get update` command with root privileges, like this:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then you will not get the `E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)` error message.

To install updates with the `apt-get upgrade` command also requires using sudo like this:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: It worked but why was that error coming up?

Comment: You need to use `sudo` before the `apt-get update` command to run the command with root privileges, because when the command pulls down the latest list of software from each archive it knows about, it writes the changes in the list of software from each archive it knows about to a file(s) that is owned by root. To install upgrades with the `apt-get upgrade` command also requires using sudo like this: `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: there is one more error that comes up when i open social engineer toolkit. Any solution?

Comment: 1. Open the terminal 2. Type  `sudo su` (to become a root user). 3. Type `setoolkit` 4. If you get an error message, copy the text of the error message and paste it into another answer. 5. Also read this: [Using the Social Engineering Toolkit In Kali Linux](http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/2015/06/using-the-social-engineering-toolkit-in-kali-linux/#.VoJer15CJC0) to see some screenshots of the Social Engineering Toolkit.

Comment: thanks it worked. Is there anyway to login as admin in kali to avoid these errors?

Comment: Oh wow, don't ever do that, or your whole operating system can get hosed. Instead there are two different ways to do it, the good way and the bad way. 1. good way - from the terminal become root for the terminal session until you exit with the command `sudo su` 2. bad way - open a graphical application as root using the command `gksu application-name` but first you have to install the `gksu` package (graphical frontend to `su`) using the command `sudo apt-get install gksu`

Comment: The reason why the good way is a good way is that the only graphical app that most Linux desktop users ever need to run as root is the text editor and there is a preinstalled text editor that runs only from the terminal just for that purpose called `nano`. To use nano to edit a file called FILE that is located in the current directory use the command `sudo nano FILE`

Comment: Thank you very much @karel for all your help and knowledge that you shared .